# Lambda invocation failed with status: 403 on new AWS region

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I enabled a new AWS region (Africa, Cape Town)

I created a new lambda on the new region. I connected the mentioned lambda to my API-Gateway located in Frankfurt region and when trying to access it, there is a internal server error.

CloudWatch shows the following:

```
(ee2d73a9-e0ff-4ba2-a445-4348e86bcfc1) Lambda invocation failed with status: 403. Lambda request id: ed3b6fc8-0959-4f43-8c3c-32d6c811e9f2
(ee2d73a9-e0ff-4ba2-a445-4348e86bcfc1) Execution failed due to configuration error: The security token included in the request is invalid
```

However, when I create another API Gateway in Africa, I can only access African Lambdas, and I get the same error trying to access anything outside Africa.

Any solutions?

Comment: The error says "The security token included in the request is invalid." So you don't have to check the permissions for now. Check if you have integrated via proxy or not a direct lambda integration (by invoke arn)then the region should be correct. Most of the time this error comes when we configure different region for the request and try to access a resource in another region.